# Can infrared light pass through solid materials

Tags: experimental-physics, material-science, infrared-radiation

I have an IR sensor at about few tens of mm (millimeter) from a heating source (incandescent bulb or heating element). The phototransistor in my sensor is lead lined but I guess it is sensitive to a wide range of IR. The IR sensor and the heating source are to be separated by either a powder coated MS (Mild Steel) sheet, or SS (Stainless Steel) sheet, or transparent Perspex, Or Black PVC Sheet, or the regular brown cardboard sheet.

I would like to avoid any noise from this heating source into my IR sensor.

I guess some interference might be expected when using transparent Perspex, but is interference to be expected with the other opaque options?

Comment: [Infrared Transparent Materials](https://infraredtraininginstitute.com/thermograpahy-information/infrared-transparent-materials/)